# Terminal window doesn't show my input after using popen() in my program

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, pipe

In my **C++** program I use `popen()` to read video frames with **ffmpeg**. When program stops on it's own or I close it with `Ctrl+C` everything I type into terminal just never appears (but it's there). I do close pipe with `pclose()`. When I try to build my program again and it fails so `gcc` prints errors - it fixes itself. **Ubuntu 18.04.3, kernel 5.4**

Is it terminal window's bug or I misunderstand pipes in some way?

Comment: You misunderstand processes, not pipes. You must collect the process status of the process you started with `popen` before it can go away. `STDIN` is still connected to the dead `ffmpeg`. Make sure you use `pclose` on the `popen` file descriptor.

Comment: @waltinator thank you for your comment. I do close p̶i̶p̶e̶ process with it's **id** like this: `auto pid = popen(); ...; pclose(pid);`. Is there a way maybe to reglue `STDIN` back to original process to continue using console or somehow start **ffmpeg** more deeply under the hood (**ffmpeg** prints a lot of video into into console which I also don't need)?

Comment: Does `reset` fix this? Check the output of `stty -a` normally and after this happens, do you spot any difference, especially an `echo` vs. `-echo`? Maybe ffmpeg leaves your tty line in `stty -echo` mode, in which case bash (readline) decides not to echo back your keypresses (it's unclear to me why).

Comment: @egmont `reset` does fix it (which already almost solved the problem). `stty -a` outputs are the same except that when everything's _OK_ these options have **no** `-` signs before them: `brkint icrnl ixon icanon echo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had a similar problem with python Popen solved it by adding `-nostdin` flag to ffmpeg command
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329483/python-subprocess-popen-ffmpeg-breaks-terminal-input